# is there any reliable way to store record in server 1 and image of record in server 2

Tags: php, mysql

in my android app i need to send a record to my "php server" and save images of this record to another "file server". and both of these jobs are need to down together like a transaction

i can send all data (text and images) to "php server". then save record and after that send images to "file server". but i have bandwidth limit on my "php server".

and another way is to sending all data (text and images) to file server (my file server support php script) and then send texts to "php server" and after that when i get success result save images to disk. 

i'm new with php and i want to ask is there any better way to do this ?

now i'm using this secound way 
my current code in file server is:

```
$data = array(
    'tag' => "createProduct",
    'token' => "$token",
    'shop_uid' => $shop_uid,
    'image1' => $image1_name,
    'image2' => $image2_name,
    'image3' => $image3_name,
    'image4' => $image4_name,
    'image5' => $image5_name,
    'name' => $name,
    'description' => $description
);
# Create a connection
$url = 'http://myhost.com/myproject/function.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
# Form data string
$postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
# Setting our options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
# Get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response == null) {
    // failed
    echo "{\"result\":0,\"messageCode\":19}";
} else {
    // save images
    if ($image1 != "") storeProductImage($image1_name, $image1);
    if ($image2 != "") storeProductImage($image2_name, $image2);
    if ($image3 != "") storeProductImage($image3_name, $image3);
    if ($image4 != "") storeProductImage($image4_name, $image4);
    if ($image5 != "") storeProductImage($image5_name, $image5);

    // send ok result to client
    echo $response;

}
```